# How to make an argument into a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

If I were to create a function:

```
def function(x, y):
    """A simple function, but 'y' will be a tuple.
    """
    function = (a*b) + x
```

I'd like `y` to be (a, b), so when it comes to printing it out, I would have to do:

```
print function(3,(4, 5))
=23
```

Where x is 3, a is 4 and b is 5. I understand that I can do this without having to turn the argument into a tuple, but it's an assignment I've been given and I have to do it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpack `y` into `a` and `b`

```
>>> def function(x, y):
...     """A simple function, but 'y' will be a tuple.
...     """
...     a,b = y
...     return (a*b) + x
... 
>>> print function(3,(4, 5))
23
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the print statement, we can see you are using Python2, so you can unpack the tuple in the function declaration like this

```
def function(x, (a, b)):
    """A simple function
    """
    return (a * b) + x

print function(3,(4, 5))
```

This syntax is no longer allowed in Python3, however running the script through "[2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#using-2to3)" yields

```
def function(x, xxx_todo_changeme):
    """A simple function
    """
    (a, b) = xxx_todo_changeme
    return (a * b) + x
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) lib and unpack with `*`:

```
from operator import mul
def function(x, y):
   """A simple function, but 'y' will be a tuple.
       """
   return x + mul(*y)

print(function(1,(3,4)))
```

Will output

```
13
```